# Seven-body-mechanism in Modelica

Tags: physics, modelica

I have to model a "seven-body-mechanism" in Modelica: [image]

The initial angles are given: 
Starting with the left side (K5 and K7):

The Modelica Model:

[image]

- Is it possible to model for example K5 as one body-shape and just specify the center of mass?
- Where can I set the initial angles for K5 and K7? In the model "revolute2" it is possible to set one "phi_start"
- Which models should I use for the "fixed" B and O? There is this parameter: Position vector from world frame to frame_b, resolved in world frame.

edit: I think i can fix the problem with 2 different angles - I just added another revolute:
[image]

The next problem I have: how to model the revolute where K5 and K4 meet? I am not sure if i should also use 2 revolutes? How to model the fixes B and O? A is fixed to the origin, but I am not sure which position vector for B and O.

I always get an error "all forces connot be uniquely calculated"

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Examples.Loops.PlanarLoops_analytic example, this contains an example of the K4, K5, K6 and K7 mechanism.  In this mechanism set the start value of the Revolute.

Answer (score 0):

Well the crucial part in the mechanism is the connection between O and B (planar four link) which can be solved using e.g. Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.Assemblies.JointRRR as demonstrated in Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Examples.Loops.PlanarLoops_analytic.

The binary members K5-K4 and K7-K6 are principally the same and they don't change the degrees of freedom of the abovementioned planar four link. So they have to be modelled in the same way (which means the revolute2 and revolute6 must be instantiated twice in your model) and be connected similarly to the planar four link once it is properly parameterized and initiated.

Optionally, you can model the mechanism using the [PlanarMechanics](https://github.com/dzimmer/PlanarMechanics) library.